# Gsap.js - moving a 3d object along a path

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, three.js, gsap

so I am new to modules, three and gsap
and what i am trying to do is move a 3d object alone a path
now i have this which is "common js" and not via modules which works fine:
https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/zYZoYpV

and i'm trying to add it to my pen here which is via modules:
https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/abJmVwo

and i keep getting these two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘position’ of undefined
line: 163

Uncaught TypeError: setX is not a function
line: 168
```

am i missing something? can someone point me in the right direction please
thanks for reading

Comment: Why are you importing absolute urls? If you know it works with the assets, use npm/yarn to  install the modules and import them using `import gsap from 'gsap'`

Comment: makes no difference here's an updated pen: https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/ZEeBQGz rotation seems messed up

Comment: You've said it works fine as common js modules, setup your working example proving that common js & your man walking around works as expected, they're two very different examples mate

Comment: @ShannonHochkins See my answer

Answer (score 0):

So after posting on gsap forums apparently the motion path plugin doesn't really work well with three.js so i'll leave this comment i got on gsap for anyone who has the same problem and wants an alternative solution:

> The MotionPathPlugin isn't really designed to work with three.js at the moment. That might come at later date.
>
> Using that proxy method just isn't going to be accurate because the plugin really only handles position and rotation in 2d.
>
> Using constructs that three.js already provides would be a much better option.
>
> https://observablehq.com/@rveciana/three-js-object-moving-object-along-path
>
> That doesn't mean you can't control it with gsap. Like here, the tubePerc is being animated with gsap, which controls the movement along the path.

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/28242-motion-paths-and-3d-objects-gsapjs-and-threejs/